how to maintain beginedit with ProcessCmdKey in datagridview with vb.net
I'm trying to maintain beginedit with ProcessCmdKey in datagridview with vb.net
So I want to tab once in keyboard then beginedit in the productname column and double tab or twice tab in keyboard then beginedit in the qty column, after finishing typing or edited or already containing a value of more than 0 in the qty column of the datagridview then automatically move the new row in the productname column.
Is it possible to apply automatically ?
Please guide me
Thanks
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form9

    Private list As BindingList(Of ProductFinaltrial) = Nothing
    Private bindingSource As BindingSource = Nothing
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ' Our collection holding products
        list = New BindingList(Of ProductFinaltrial)()
        ' I've set up columns manually (with applied binding),
        ' so switch generating columns off.
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        ' Disable adding new row
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        ' Create our medium between grid and collection
        bindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = list}
        ' Set binding
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource
        DataGridView1.Columns("Unit").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("No").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prp").ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Columns("Prs").ReadOnly = True
        bindingSource.AddNew()
        DataGridView1.Select()
    End Sub
    Private Function GetSELECT() As ProductFinaltrial
        Return If(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count = 0, Nothing, TryCast(DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).OwningRow.DataBoundItem, ProductFinaltrial))
    End Function
    Private Sub setnounitPrpprs()
        Dim i = 1
        Dim bs = TryCast(bindingSource.DataSource, BindingList(Of ProductFinaltrial))
        For Each row As ProductFinaltrial In bs
            row.No = i
            row.Unit = "pcs"
            row.Prp = i
            row.Prs = i
            i += 1
        Next
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Tab AndAlso CBool(Keys.Enter) Then
            Dim SelectDgv = GetSELECT()
            If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Productname").Value?.ToString()) And Not CInt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Qty").Value) = 0 Then
                    bindingSource.AddNew()
                End If
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        setnounitPrpprs()
        Dim QTY As Integer = Nothing
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value.ToString(), QTY) Then
                QTY = 0
            End If
        Else
            QTY = 0
        End If
        DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("QTY").Value = QTY
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ProductFinaltrial
    Public Property No As Integer?
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Prp As Integer?
    Public Property Prs As Integer?
    Public Property Qty As Integer?

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{ProductName}"
    End Function

End Class

